# Adding multiple images in a LaTeX document in the same "area"

Tags: floats, numbering

Is it possible to add multiple images to a given are in a LaTeX document.

What I want to achieve is having three images aligned horizontally, and each one of them corresponding letters a), b), and c) respectively. In the caption I want to explain what Fig X.a) is and then Fig X.b) and then Fig X.c)

Do I incorporate this 3 figures in one larger figure and import it in latex? or can I do it in another fashion. How do I add the letter a) b) c) to the figures? Should I add them to the figures with Paint or other software, or there is a LaTeX way of assigning letters to figures?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width = 2in]{something}}
\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width = 2in]{something}}
\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width = 2in]{something}}
\caption{}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I believe this is what you are asking for.

If you want, you can add:

```
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width = 2in]{something}} &
\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width = 2in]{something}} &
\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width = 2in]{something}}
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

Comment: Dear dustin, I agree this is what I was looking for... I think this is a possible solution but in a different way, right? http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions

@dustin

Comment: If you're using `[H]`, please also reference the FAQs: [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](http://goo.gl/Qzz31) and [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](http://goo.gl/290dD).

Comment: @dustin: Then, of course, you also don't need the [`float` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/float).