# Include subfigures in poster

Tags: floats, posters

I am trying to write a poster for a conference presentation, so far everything works fine except for 2 figures that I want to include (both should be on the same row with one common caption). I keep getting errors for some reason.The Packages that I am using are:

```
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{epsf}
\usepackage{graphicx,psfrag,color,pstcol,pst-grad}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{multicol}
  \usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,latexsym,amssymb,enumerate,amsthm,array,bm,amscd,overcite,psfrag,epsfig}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{subfig}
```

I have tried using:

```
\begin{center}

\mbox{\subfigure%[Feasible Case \label{fig:Feas_Case}]
{\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{FeasibleCase.eps} }\qquad
\subfigure%[Infeasible Case \label{fig:Infeas_Case}]
{\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{InfeasibleCase.eps} }
}
\captionof{figure}{My Feas-inf figures} 
\label{fig:Feas_Infeas}

\end{center}
```

But I keep getting these errors:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \subfigure
{\includegraphics [scale=0.4]{FeasibleCase.eps} }\qqua...
l.593 }
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
File: FeasibleCase.eps Graphic file (type eps)
<FeasibleCase.eps>
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...easibleCase.eps} }\qquad \subfigure
{\includegraphics [scale=0...
l.593 }
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
File: InfeasibleCase.eps Graphic file (type eps)
<InfeasibleCase.eps>
```

I am not sure what to do to fix this. Any idea? (I have also tried using the package \usepackage{subfigure} instead of \usepackage{subfig}, and that gives me even more errors.)

Comment: On my post here, I have 2 examples on how to setup figures that may help you http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122314/figures-what-is-the-difference-between-using-subfig-or-subfigure Also, here is another example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121667/adding-multiple-images-in-a-latex-document-in-the-same-area/121668#121668

Comment: There's no `\subfigure` command in the `subfig` package; the right command is `\subfloat`.

Comment: @dustin: I have used one of your example:                        \begin{tabular}{cc}
    \subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width =     2in]{FeasibleCase.eps}} &
    \subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width =     2in]{InfeasibleCase.eps}} 
    \end{tabular}    but it did NOT work unfortunately, it is giving me the error: ! LaTeX Error: \subfloat outside float.

Comment: I also posted one for you too but good you got it to work.

Comment: @dustin: I have used one of your example: \begin{tabular}{cc} \subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width = 2in]{FeasibleCase.eps}} & \subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width = 2in]{InfeasibleCase.eps}} \end{tabular} but it did NOT work unfortunately, it is giving me the error: ! LaTeX Error: \subfloat outside float

Comment: Can you post the full error message in your post?

Comment: Load the `\usepackage{float}`.  Does this correct the problem?

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{cc}
    \subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width = 1.5in]{something}} &
    \subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width = 1.5in]{something}}
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This should do the job for you:

[image]

Comment: when I use my eps figures in the above code (in a new file), the figures are black for some reason. Also, when I use the above code and the packages in the preamble for my poster, it still gives me an error unfortunately

Comment: Never mind! I think the error came from the fact that I already had a '\usepackage{graphicx}', and adding the \usepackage[demo]{graphicx} probably caused some sort of incompatibility... But now it works just fine :) Thanks!!!