# Images in a presentation

Tags: beamer, graphics, presentations

This is my first time being here. The site is such an asset. Asking this only because I couldn't get it done.
**Question.** I want to insert two (may be three) images with captions for each.  I was referring [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121667/adding-multiple-images-in-a-latex-document-in-the-same-area):
This is my code for that particular frame:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

    \begin{frame}
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
    \subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width = 2in]{image1.jpg}} &
    \subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width = 2in]{image2.jpg}} 
    \end{tabular}
    \end{frame}
```

I get an error saying: `\subfloat outside float`. I'm using the online `.tex` editor Overleaf.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

In a presentation often have little sense numbered subcaptions and the superfluous "Figure:" statement. As the issue  with all of this is solved in another answer, my suggestion is not use at all `figure` floats, captions or any related package:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}\centering
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{.3\linewidth}\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}\par 
The image A
\end{column}
\begin{column}{.3\linewidth}\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}\par 
The image B
\end{column}
\begin{column}{.3\linewidth}\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}\par 
The image C
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\bigskip
The main caption
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why not a `tabular`?

Comment: @egreg  This morning I was not quite "tabulator".  That's all. `:D`

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use `figure` outside (it's a float and it's for images):

```
\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}[h] %<-- NEW
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width = 2in]{image1.jpg}} &
\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width = 2in]{image2.jpg}} 
\end{tabular}
\end{figure} %<-- NEW
\end{frame}
```

---

If you'd like to have many options with your captions probably you should switch to the package `subcaption` (uses `caption`) and this approach:

```
\begin{frame}
   \begin{figure}
        \begin{subfigure}{.45\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width = \linewidth]{example-image-a.jpg}
            \caption{Caption}
        \end{subfigure}\hfill
        \begin{subfigure}{.45\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width = \linewidth]{example-image-b.jpg}
            \caption{Caption}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{Test}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: @ TeXnician, it worked. Thank you very much. Could you please tell me how to adjust the dimensions of the images ?

Comment: @Eureka There is a parameter `width` you already issued and adjusted.

Comment: the way it appears now is one image is taller than the other and two are closer to each other. That's what I want to change.

Comment: @Eureka Please edit your question and post a screenshot of what you want to adjust.

Comment: if you use, for example `\includegraphics[width = \linewidth]{example-image-b.jpg}`, than \centering its position inside `subfigure` has no sense ... and can/should be omitted :)

Comment: @Zarko I just inserted it for the case the OP wants to adjust the width. The example images have the same height. Other images may need to be adjusted.